# Toolbar issues with iOS 7/8

Tags: ios, hide, toolbar

I am having some trouble hiding toolbar (Bottom bar) on one of the view controllers in my iOS app. So I have a home view controller which has a navigation bar and a toolbar. Then a UIPageViewController is pushed (a tutorial for the app). There should be no navigation or toolbar on this screen.

I used the standard code to hide the toolbar. Here it is:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
```

It works in iOS 8 but not in iOS 7. I tried many variations and tried putting it in viewDidLayoutSubviews, viewWillAppear, viewDidappear and also right before pushing the view controller. Nothing works. Hiding navigation bar worked without issues.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have a UIToolBar at the bottom of your home view controller or is it a UITabBar?

Comment: UIToolBar of the navigation controller.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard to set up the navigation controller, toolbar, and the home view controller? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: No I am just using code to set everything up. I'm sure the code is working because it behaves as expected on iOS 8 + the code works for all other screens in the app for both iOS 7 and 8 + believe it or not, when I ran it this afternoon it suddenly started working but after a while it stopped working again.

Answer (score 0):

A better property to use when you want the toolbar hidden when pushing is setting `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `YES` on the `UIViewController` you are pushing.

Comment: I tried it. Not working. Any idea why it is behaving differently on iOS 8?

Comment: Where are you placing the code that sets the destination ViewControllers' hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property? It needs to be before you push the view controller, and you need to set it on the viewController you are pushing.

Comment: Yes I'm doing that. I tried pretty much everything. self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.pageViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    self.navigationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_pageViewController animated:NO];